# How to deal with a BIP7059 error "Failed to find message element" on a publication node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I'm getting 'Failed to find message element' when I output a well formed message to a publication node on IIB.

I've tried changing the XML message tree but the error still remains same. Anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Put a Trace Node after the Node where you build the message and and write the contents into a file.

In the Trace Node use ${Root} so you can see everything.

[image]

It produces the output below, which is from a sample that I had to hand.
Note the three parsers which have the form [{*ParserName*} : {*ParserInstance*}]  that have been attached to the element tree. Namely SOAPRoot, MQPROPERTYPARSER, and SOAP.

In your case you are looking for the XMLNSC Parser, by preference, although you may see XMLNS or even the really old XML parser attached.

```
Trace showing the content of the message

( ['SOAPRoot' : 0x1b633e9ff60]
  (0x01000000:Name  ):Properties = ( ['MQPROPERTYPARSER' : 0x1b406434d80]
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageSet             = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageType            = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageFormat          = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Encoding               = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):CodedCharSetId         = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Transactional          = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Persistence            = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):CreationTime           = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ExpirationTime         = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Priority               = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyIdentifier        = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyProtocol          = 'SOAP-AXIS2' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Topic                  = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ContentType            = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceType     = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceToken    = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourcePassword = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceIssuedBy = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedType     = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedToken    = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedPassword = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedIssuedBy = NULL
  )
  (0x01000000:Folder):SOAP       = ( ['SOAP' : 0x1b62a218430]
    (0x01000000:Folder):Context = (
      (0x01000000:Folder):Namespace = (
        (0x03000102:NamespaceDecl)xmlns:soap = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000102:NamespaceDecl)xmlns:acc  = 'http://acc' (CHARACTER)
      )
    )
    (0x01000000:Folder):Body    = (
      (0x01000000:Folder)http://acc:Response = (
        (0x03000000:PCDataField)http://acc:ReqID       = 'ID102' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:PCDataField)http://acc:CompanyName = 'Universal Happiness' (CHARACTER)
        (0x01000000:Folder     )http://acc:Employee    = (
          (0x03000000:PCDataField)http://acc:id   = 'E100' (CHARACTER)
          (0x03000000:PCDataField)http://acc:name = 'John' (CHARACTER)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

If you are validating against a schema then you can use the Trace Node output to check your message against that schema paying attention to the presence or absence of mandatory aggregates and fields, also their order.

The following text is from the [web page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.bipmsgs.doc/ay_bip7.htm) containing the description of the error message.

```
BIP7059
    Failed to navigate to message element <insert_1>.
Severity
    30 : Severe error
Explanation
    While attempting to explore the contents of a message an error 
    occurred because the element <insert_1> was missing or unreachable.
Response
    This is an internal error and you should contact your IBM support center.
```

Have a look at your logs and see if the name in insert_1 provides a clue.

NOTE: The text tells you it's an internal error and you may indeed need to contact IBM Support.